# Login and registration example in Django with different user table

Tags: python, django

I am quite new to Django, I need a example code for creating login and registration form and a default page which a user can see only after logged in.

Here important thing is that i want to use different table for users other than the auth_user table for admin. These users can logged in and able to perform some functionality.

Please suggest me if its best way to have different table users for such customers? Or i can use the same auth_user table.

Comment: You can easily create a different model for Users. But why not use the auth_user?

Comment: I don't want other user to get access for admin section. This is the main reason i want to use different table.

Comment: @AnilSharma `is_superuser` flag of User can only access to Admin page!

Comment: if you have more than one user write custom backend

Answer (score 3):

You can specify different permissions in the auth_user table using the `is_superuser` and `is_staff` boolean attributes in the model.

Maintaining the session and permissions is easier if you use the auth_user table

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want [Creating Custom User models in Django.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)